# Regular Expressions and Relative File Paths

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match the folder name in a relative path using C#. I am using the expression: `"/(.*)?/"` and reversing the matching from left to right to right to left.
When I pass `"images/gringo/"` into the regular expression, it correctly gives me `"gringo"` in the first group - I'm only interested in what is between the brackets.
When I pass in `"images/"`, it fails to pick up `"images"`. 
I have tried using `[/^]` and `[/$]` but neither work.

Thanks,
David

Comment: a regex isn't always the answer! in this case, the tool-provided libraries are much easier !   :)

Answer (score 13):

You're probably better off using the [System.IO.DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) class to interpret your relative path. You can then pick off folder or file names using its members:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("images/gringo/");
Console.Out.WriteLine(di.Name);
```

This will be much safer than any regexps you could use.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this.  Use System.IO.Path to break apart path parts and then compare them.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
"([^/]+)/?$"
```

- 1 or more non / characters
- Optional /
- End of string

But as [@Blair Conrad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246656/regular-expressions-and-relative-file-paths#246663) says - better to go with a class that encapsulates this for you....

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with the "*don't do it this way*" answers, but, since it's tagged "*regex*"...

- You don't need the `?`.  `*` already accepts 0 repetitions as a match, so `(.*)` is exactly equivalent to `(.*)?`
- You rarely actually want to use `.*` anyhow.  If you're trying to capture what's between a pair of slashes, use `/([^/]*)/` or else testing against "*foo/bar/baz/*" will (on most regex implementations) return a single match for "*bar/baz*" instead of matching "*bar*" and "*baz*" separately.